# How to reorder one set of data points to minimize error with another set of data points

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, scipy

I have the following set of 15 data points:

```
[0.287 , 0.0691, 0.856, 0.731, 0.895, 0.76, 0.496, 0.749, 0.77, 0.684, 0.667, 0.386, 0.4, 0.334, 0.346]
```

And I would like the order of these data points to be changed so to minimize the error with the following set of 15 data points:

```
[0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.6, 0.5, 0.4, 0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1]
```

I could just try all permutations of the first set of data points and see which one gives the smallest error but that would take forever...

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming by *error* you mean the summed absolute difference. It is not difficult to check that this error is minimized when `a` and `b` have the same rank order. The best reordering of `a` can thus be obtained using `argsort`

```
>>> a = np.array([0.287 , 0.0691, 0.856 , 0.731 , 0.895 , 0.76 , 0.496 , 0.749 , 0.77 , 0.684 , 0.667 , 0.386 , 0.4 , 0.334 , 0.346 ])
>>> b = np.array([0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.6, 0.5, 0.4, 0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1])
>>> 
>>> best_shuffle = np.empty(a.size,int)
>>> best_shuffle[b.argsort(kind="stable")] = a.argsort(kind="stable")
>>> 
>>> np.abs(b-a[best_shuffle]).sum()
1.3499000000000005
```